# How to get raw Kinect range data?

Tags: kinect-sdk, azurekinect

Working with Azure Kinect.  in the docs, Microsoft explains that the depth image is a processed output from the raw range data.  How do I / is it possible / to obtain the raw range data ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get the raw range data.